# List available video modes using GLFW

Tags: c++, c, opengl, glfw

I am trying to retrieve a list of the available video modes for my monitor using GLFW 3, but I'm struggling to understand the GLFW help pages.

I can retrieve the current video mode as follows:

```
int county
const GLFWvidmode* modes = glfwGetVideoModes(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor(), &county);

int width = modes->width;
int height = modes->height;
```

but how do I retrieve a list of video modes?  It should be possible according to this:

http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/monitor.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will give you an array of modes which the size is given by `county` (variable name shown in your code).
So you need to loop through `modes` from zero to less than `county`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think I'm being pretty stupid though, because I'm not sure how to index the modes vector.  Would you mind showing me an example?  Thanks so much.

Comment: You might try using `modes` just like an array like this: `modes[i].width, modes[i].height`.

Comment: Ah yes thank you, I realise now modes is a structure.  Thanks both